# Eqs of motion under dual field strength tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus, yang-mills

With a $SU(2)$-invariant Lagrangian of the form

$$
{\cal L} = -\frac{1}{2g^2}tr\{F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}\} - \frac{\theta}{2g^2}tr\{F_{\mu\nu}\widetilde{F}^{\mu\nu}\},\quad \widetilde{F}^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}
$$

in principle, Euler-Lagrange equations cannot be unchanged with respect of those given by

$$
{\cal L}_1 = -\frac{1}{2g^2}tr\{F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}\}
$$

since

$$
tr\{F_{\mu\nu}\widetilde{F}^{\mu\nu}\} = \partial_\alpha K^\alpha
$$

Nevertheless, I computed the equations without considering this and I got

$$
\partial_\alpha \left( F^{b, \alpha\beta} + \frac{\theta}{2}\widetilde{F}^{b, \alpha\beta} \right) - g\epsilon^{bda}A_\nu^d \left( F^{a, \beta\nu} + \frac{\theta}{2}\widetilde{F}^{a, \beta\nu} \right) = 0,
$$

where there's implicit sum on repeated Latin indices, while Greek ones are summed according to Einstein's rule of repeated indices. Also,

$$
F_{\mu\nu} = F^c_{\mu\nu}\sigma^c/2, \quad F^c_{\mu\nu} = 2g\partial_{[\mu}A^c_{\nu]} + g^2A^a_{\mu}A^b_\nu\epsilon^{abc}
$$

with $\sigma^c$ the $c$th Pauli matrix and the anti-symmetrizer defined as

$$
\hat{O}_{[\mu\nu]} = \frac{1}{2}(\hat{O}_{\mu\nu} - \hat{O}_{\nu\mu})
$$

So from the reason above the part on $\widetilde{F}$ should cancel, but how to prove it?

Comment: I think someone gave a solution that I was going to award with the bounty, but it has disappeared...